# android how to make validation url available from retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

To check whether youtube url is available I used retrofit, it works well but I want to use it as validation I got stuck, here's my code :

**CheckUrlHelper.java**

```
private static final String BASE_URL= "https://youtu.be/";    
public void CheckUrl(String youtube_id)
        {
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL+youtube_id).build();
    
            Call<ResponseBody> call= retrofit.create(CheckUrlAvailable.class).checkUrl();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    //Log.d("","response : "+response);
                    if(response.code() == 200)
                    {
                        result = "true";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "false";               
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    result = "false";
                }
        });
            listener.getResult(result);
        }
    
        public interface callbackListener {
            void getResult(String result);
        }
```

I've tried using interface like code on above but caused error.

My expectation : to get result (if it possibly to get result from code whether 200, 500 or etc), so :

**MyClass.java**

```
private String error_message;

        public void onClick(View v) {
                        String video_link = editVideoLink.getText().toString();
                        CheckUrlHelper curl = new CheckUrlHelper();
                        
    /* MY Expectation */
    
        if(curl.CheckUrl(video_link) == 200){
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"url available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"url not available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

/**** Edit ****/

  String video_link = editVideoLink.getText().toString();
  if(TextUtils.is_empty(video_link){
     error_message = "Link cannot be empty";
  } else if(/* methodNamewhatever(video_link) == false*/ OR /* methodNamewhatever(video_link) == 404*/){
    error_message = "Invalid Link";
}else{
   // save
}
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error_message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

So when user put youtube id on editText and then click on submit, it could be give the result as validation.

please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created some code snippets for you just try to use to solve your issues.

**CheckUrlHelper.java**

```
    private static final String BASE_URL= "https://youtu.be/";
public void CheckUrl(String youtube_id, callbackListener listener)
{
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL+youtube_id).build();

    Boolean result = false;

    Call<ResponseBody> call= retrofit.create(CheckUrlAvailable.class).checkUrl();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            //Log.d("","response : "+response);
            if(response.code() == 200)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
            listener.getResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            result = false;
            listener.getResult(result);
        }
    });
    
}

public interface callbackListener {
    void getResult(Boolean result);
}
```

And modify your click code in

**MyClass.java**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String video_link = editVideoLink.getText().toString();
    CheckUrlHelper curl = new CheckUrlHelper();
    //curl.CheckUrl(video_link);

    curl.CheckUrl(video_link, new callbackListener() {
        @Override
        public void getResult(Boolean result) {
            if(result){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"url available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"url not available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Hopefully this will solve your problems.

Comment: Hello, you all's codes **works well**, but not as my expectation, please see MyClass.java I had edit my post and give more complete code, so what I expect is create method that able to connected to retrofit and then use it to validate URL link. If my way is wrong please tell me another solution as alternatives. Thanks

Comment: You're thinking about blocking network call but android doesn't allow network call in Main Thread. You can do as you are thinking but it required another background thread to perform your network operation.
Try to call execute method of retrofit instead enqueue , execute perform same thread (blocking) network call. Or best to use my provided solution for non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you misplaced the listener's location. Instead of calling it out of all functions, you need to call it once in each method in order to get the result after the response is triggered in `onResponse` and `onFailure` callbacks.

So you have to change your code to be like this

```java
    private static final String BASE_URL= "https://youtu.be/";
public void CheckUrl(String youtube_id, callbackListener listener)
{
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL+youtube_id).build();

    Boolean result = false;

    Call<ResponseBody> call= retrofit.create(CheckUrlAvailable.class).checkUrl();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            //Log.d("","response : "+response);
            if(response.code() == 200)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
            listener.getResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            result = false;
            listener.getResult(result);
        }
    });
    
}

public interface callbackListener {
    void getResult(Boolean result);
}
```